# Script for Blender 2.8 grease pencil that automatically fills in all closed lines

Tags: python, blender

I need a Blender 2.8 script that automatically fills in all closed lines and circles for grease pencil.

For example. https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1e5f.png automatically becomes https://i.stack.imgur.com/yndEa.png

Comment: What have you tried so far? You can't really expect people to do all the work for you

Comment: I haven't tried anything so far. I would like to know if this script is possible and any suggestions of ways I go about it.

Answer (score -1):

It isn't about closing the stroke paths, it is just enabling the fill for each material.

The current object has a list of materials, you can loop through that and enable the show_fill for each one.

```
for s in bpy.context.object.material_slots:
    s.material.grease_pencil.show_fill = True
```

This will fail if the current object is not a grease pencil, so if you want something more generic, you should check that `object.type == 'GPENCIL'`